# Executing a member function of a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am trying to experiment the C++11 threads in a way that it accepts a member function of a class  as a parameter into the thread constructor as shown in the first code snippet below on line 20 that is marked . The class definition is given in the 2nd code snippet. When this code is compiled, I am getting a bunch of errors shown in the 3rd snippet. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**SNIPPET 1: Thread initialization (main_app.cpp)**

```
#include <thread>
#include "ServiceRegistrar.hpp"

#define SERVER_TYPE  100065
#define SERVER_INST_LOWER  1
#define SERVER_INST_UPPER  2
#define TIMEOUT  500000

int main()
{
  ServiceRegistrar sr1(SERVER_TYPE, TIMEOUT, SERVER_INST_LOWER, SERVER_INST_LOWER);
      /*LINE 20 is the following*/
  std::thread t(&ServiceRegistrar::subscribe2TopologyServer, sr1);
t.join();
  sr1.publishForSRs();

}
```

**SNIPPET 2: Class definition**

```
class ServiceRegistrar
{
  public:
    ServiceRegistrar(int serverType, int serverTimeOut, int serverInstanceLower, int serverInstanceUpper)
       : mServerType(serverType),
         mServerTimeOut(serverTimeOut),
         mServerInstanceLower(serverInstanceLower),
         mServerInstanceUpper(serverInstanceUpper)
         { }

     void subscribe2TopologyServer();
     void publishForSRs();
     void publishForServices();

  private:
     int mServerType;
     int mServerTimeOut;
     int mServerInstanceLower;
         int mServerInstanceUpper;           
  };
```

**SNIPPET 3: Compilation output**

```
  $ g++ -g -c -Wall -std=c++11 main_app.cpp -pthread
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ratio:38:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/chrono:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:38,
             from main_app.cpp:8:
  /usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct    std::_Result_of_impl<false, false, std::_Mem_fn<void (ServiceRegistrar::*)()>,    ServiceRegistrar>’:
  /usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:1857:12:   required from ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (ServiceRegistrar::*)()>(ServiceRegistrar)>’
  /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1563:61:   required from ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (ServiceRegistrar::*)()>(ServiceRegistrar)>’
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:133:9:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&,  _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (ServiceRegistrar::*)(); _Args = {ServiceRegistrar&}]’
 main_app.cpp:20:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:1834:9: error: no match for call to     ‘ (std::_Mem_fn<void (ServiceRegistrar::*)()>) (ServiceRegistrar)’
```

Comment: ewwww very unnecessary macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it's a [gcc 4.7 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080200/gcc-4-7-2-stdthread-with-pointer-to-member-function)...use

```
std::thread t(&ServiceRegistrar::subscribe2TopologyServer, &sr1);
```

instead.

EDIT: actually, you probably don't want to be copying `sr1` to the thread-local-storage of `t`, so this is better anyway.

Comment: Bug or not, you almost certainly want to bind to a pointer or reference here anyway.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yep, just added that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
std::thread t(std::bind(&ServiceRegistrar::subscribe2TopologyServer, sr1));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That masks the problem, since `bind` doesn't share the same bug as `thread`. But binding to a copy of `sr1` is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.